# java, when i use doublebuffering, painted image is expanded

Tags: java

when i use doublebuffering, painted image is expanded with white background.
Is there something wrong?

```
enter code here
private Image image_buffer;
private Graphics graphics_buffer

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    buffering(img1, x1, 40, g);
}

public void buffering(Image img, int x, int y, Graphics g){
    image_buffer = createImage(100,100);
    graphics_buffer = image_buffer.getGraphics();
    buffer.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
    g.drawImage(image_buffer, x, y, this);
}
```

Comment: Do all variables and methods need to have the word "buffer" in them?

Comment: buffer, image_buffer, image_buffer, bufferedImage etc.. Please change your variable names thats not understable..

Comment: sorry for inpropriate variables. i fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Why not replace your code with just:-

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(img1, x1, 40, this);
}
```

The reason you have a white background is because you're creating a 100x100 "canvas", and drawing on that.

Comment: because when the image move to right side, there is imageblinking. so i used doublebuffering

Comment: You should use BufferStrategy, it's much easier.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html